# Simple graph with lowest maximal betweenness centrality

Tags: graph-theory, network

What are the [simple graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Simple_graph) on $n$ vertices and at most $m$ edges, which have the lowest maximal geodesic [betweenness centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality)?

To clarify, the maximal geodesic betweenness centrality $B^*$ of a graph $G$ is defined as $B^* = \max_vB(v)$, where $B(v)$ is the geodesic betweenness centrality of node $v$.

Trivially, if $m = {n \choose 2}$, the complete graph will minimize it. What about the intermediate $m$?

From the paper by [Guimera et al (2002)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.89.248701), it seems to indicate a homogeneous graph structure minimises $B^*$, but is there a exact description of these graphs? And a proof of optimality?